# Spring JPA feature that allows single Repo method to be reused across different entities

Tags: java, spring, jpa, graphql

I was asked this question in one of my job interviews.

Consider, we have a Spring JPA project consisting of different entities *say Employee, Supervisor, Department, Sites, etc*.

1. We need to have a Repo method, *say `findAllByName`* in such a way that this method is defined just once and reused for all our entities.
2. Further, he went on to say that this particular feature in Spring JPA negates the necessity to use GraphQL. Effectively, this feature can be harnessed to have a GraphQL like behavior using REST.

I understand for Point 1 above, `@MappedSuperClass` mechanism can be used. But, for point 2 I don't think `@MappedSuperClass` can help.

Any pointers on such a concept in Spring JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create base repository. Of course repositories extending MyBaseRepository need to be for entities with name field.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyBaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    public List<T> findAllByName(String name);
}

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MyBaseRepository<Employee,Long>{
}
```